# Using variable saved using BeanShell Sampler in Throughput Controller

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I am trying to assign a Jmeter variable to another variable in BeanShell Sampler using `vars.put("End", vars.get("homeEnd"));`. And I am using `${End}` variable in the Throughput Controller to represent percentage throughput. But getting the following error in the logs:

> jmeter.control.ThroughputController: Error parsing ${End} java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${End}"
>       at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.control.ThroughputController.getPercentThroughputAsFloat(ThroughputController.java:168)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.control.ThroughputController.decide(ThroughputController.java:203)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.control.ThroughputController.iterationStart(ThroughputController.java:239)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.fireIterationStart(GenericController.java:405)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.fireIterEvents(GenericController.java:397)

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting normally means that `End` variable is not defined. I would suggest using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to check your `homeEnd` and `End` variables values after your Beanshell Sampler Execution, if everything goes well they both should have the same non-empty value.

It also worth checking *jmeter.log* file to see any Beanshell-related errors.

See [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article for more information on JMeter scripts troubleshooting.

Comment: when i try to print "End", "homeEnd" variables in bean shell after vars.put("End", vars.get("homeEnd")); those were showing correctly

Comment: homeEnd: 40.00
End: 40.00

Comment: apart from below error in Jmeter.log, i dont see anyother warn/error messages

Comment: 2016/12/27 15:59:36 WARN  - jmeter.control.ThroughputController: Error parsing ${End} java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${End}"
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Unknown Source)
 at

Comment: It sounds like a Throughput Controller issue, can you please report it via [JMeter Bugzilla](http://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html). In the mean time you can switch to JMeter Properties, like: `props.put("End", vars.get("homeEnd"));` in Beanshell and `${__P(End,)}` in the Transaction Controller. For more information on JMeter Properties see [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) guide.